# Haskell transfer between monadic functions

Tags: sqlite, haskell, io, monads

Feel I am never going to fully grasp Haskell now. Two functions: one that counts records in a SQlite DB, so it can produce incremental IDs (`checkUniqueID`). The other one to make the records, calling on `checkUniqueID`. I just need the value over to `taskEntry` as an `Int`. I guess I am missing the knowledge to stay in the monadic realm. Code below.

```
-- checkUniqueID :: IO ()
checkUniqueID = do
  conn <- open "taglist.db"
  len <- query_ conn "SELECT (id) FROM task" :: IO [Only Int]
  let showLength = Data.List.length $ len
  close conn
  return (showLength + 1) -- for testing purposes

-- fieldnames: id, task, date_in, date_out
taskEntry :: IO ()
taskEntry = do
      putStrLn "Provide task and date due: "
      let taskIDInt = checkUniqueID -- issue here!
      task <- getLine
      date_out <- getLine
      let date_in = "today"
      conn <- open "taglist.db"
      execute conn "INSERT INTO task (id, task, date_in, date_out) VALUES (?,?,?,?)"
            (taskIDInt :: Int , task :: String , date_in :: String , date_out :: String)
      close conn
      return ()
```

Comment: for starters, the type should probably be `checkUniqueID :: IO Int` - you actually want to return something of type `Int`, besides executing an IO action. Then: `taskIDInt <- checkUniqueID`, because `checkUniqueID` is in IO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `checkUniqueID` returns an `Int`, so its type should be `IO Int`, not `IO ()`:

```
checkUniqueID :: IO Int
```

Second, within the `do` notation, the left arrow `<-` is what binds result of a monadic function to a name. You're already using it with `getLine`, so I'm not entirely sure why you would fail to use it with `checkUniqueID` as well:

```
taskIDInt <- checkUniqueID
```

Comment: I am not failing with your suggestion. I have a hard time seeing the forrest through the trees. You put me on the right track and it works! Sorry for this... Sometimes I feel a bit stupid trying monoids, applicatives, functors etc while the only thing I need to do is a simple bind of two monadic functions! Thanks